Why might Git's dubious ownership error suddenly be a problem?
I have a git repository for each of a collection of tools on a shared network folder on a closed network operating on Windows.
NETWORK
Origin Repos:
Tool1.git (bare)
Tool2.git (bare)
etc.
Public Repos:
Tool1  (for when using the tools)
Tool2  (for when using the tools)
Description
A new error "dubious ownership" has cropped up in the last few days. Never an issue before. No users were able to push/pull/merge/commit or otherwise perform git commands on even their private repos.
Potential Changes:

Lots of commits have been made recently, but no changes to the config files.
The user who originally created the repositories has transitioned jobs and his account was closed.

Why might this error suddenly be an issue?

Cropped up where? In what app/service?

Anytime a user was trying to push/pull/merge/commit/etc. In git on Windows.

Try git config --global safe.directory '*'.

Sounds like git was updated. This check has been introduced a few releases ago
